# YASVE - SQLite Version Error

Tags: xcode, macos, sqlite

This is probably a noob question but...

I finally took the plunge and updated xcode to 6 (from 3.2.6, IB plugins holdout), but kept developer target at 10.6, so I can better address all the deprecations (10.6, 10.8, 10.10) while running in Yosemite 10.10.1 server.

After addressing the 10.6 deprecations (whoa) , I get a clean build but it fails on startup:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
  Reason: Incompatible library version: CFNetwork requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libsqlite3.dylib provides version 1.0.0
(lldb)

This app uses the FMDatabase and sqlite as sub-projects, and had been working fine on 10.7.5 before updating.  I did try and build/install sqlite-autoconf-3080704.tar.gz (had been using 3080704), but that installs at /usr/local/lib and xcode isn't picking that up that or my LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't affecting the search.

So I presume I missing something. Other similar posts seem to be 3rd party package related (Ruby, FireFox, etc) but I suspect my issue is day 0 setup.

Comment: Btw, my use of the sub-projects was due to my extending FM and using some symbols that don't resolve but I do link via flags -lsqlite3.  I suspect it's a CFNetwork issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems my approach to embedding sqlite3 as a sub-project isn't feasible anymore as having migrated from xcode 3.2 - quite a jump to 6.3, the CFNetwork framework makes use of sqlite3 too.  My project's version was impacting that and the sub-projects versions were defaulted at 1. The solution was to remove this sub-project and link against the system's version: -lsqlite3 added to linker flags.

It does pose perhaps a bigger question as to whether you could still do this by altering a sub-project's compatible and version build settings but then you get into perhaps other issues (missing global sqlite3_intarray_bind) with the bits themselves, so I'll leave that for another day.